# sprite Kit moving an object - the recommended way

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I am new to the sprite Kit and I see that there are 3 different ways of moving objects:

1. position += velocity
2. create a physics body and apply impulse
3. use physicsBody.velocity property

can you please give some guidelines when to use each one of the ways? I am a bit confused, Thanks.

Comment: This question is likely to be flagged as too broad. However, if you were to post some specific situations, then these can be answered in a much more concise manner.

Comment: I think this is a good question, to give the distinction of when each is appropriate. I see tons of questions that basically come down to not understanding the distinction of when/why to use each method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. if you aren't using SKPhysicsBody for that node
2. if you want the mass of the physics body to influence the resulting velocity
3. if you want to set the body's velocity regardless of its mass